# Problems with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have just installed R version 3.6.3 along with RStudio on my Lenovo flex running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have been going through some code and ran into a curious problem.
The code I am running is from the book R for Data Science.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds) +
   geom_bar(mapping=aes(cut))
```

This works just fine. Then I try:

```
ggplot(diamonds) +
   geom_bar(mapping=aes(cut, color=cut))
```

R hangs. No plot is generated and I have to kill R. This happens with running the code in RStudio and with R with no IDE from the terminal.
The curious thing is that this code works fine with another dataset -- the `mpg` dataset (both datasets come with `ggplot2`, I believe).
Has anyone experienced the same or similar issue, and what could be causing that? The `diamonds` dataset is not very large (maybe 50,000 entries). My machine has 16GB of RAM, quad core Intel processor i7 with a GPU, so resources should not be an issue.

I appreciate any help in understanding and eventually resolving this annoying issue.

Comment: What is your RStudio and ggplot2 version, I have the same R version as you, but running on Windows and worked just fine, ggplot2 3.3.0 and RStudio 1.2.5033

Comment: I tested on a Mac, the code works with or without RStudio on R-4.0.0 with ggplot2 version 3.3.0. Does restarting R session again gives the same issue?

Comment: ggplot2 version is 3.3.2 Rstudio version 1.3.959. The problem is encountered whether I run R without Rstudio from the terminal and with Rstudio. Restarting R does not solve the problem--it will hang everytime I run the code. As I said the curious thing is the same code works just fine with a different dataset (at least one).

Comment: @Aref Can you check your ggplot2 again. I'm not seeing version 3.3.2. Maybe you somehow grabbed an unstable early release and need to downgrade.

Comment: If you need to run an old version of R, make sure you get a compatible version of `ggplot2.` If you can, just get version 4.0 and reinstall `ggplot2`. The code works great on my windows install of R 4.0.

Comment: @ToddBurusn OOPS. You are right the version I have is 3.3.1.

Comment: @markhogue as I mentioned the weird thing is why it works with the mpg dataset and not with the diamonds dataset. I will try and get R 4.0 and see what happens.

Comment: UPDATE: Reinstalled R -- now have R 4.0 -- and ggplot2 and the tidyverse packages. I still have the same issue which makes me think that it might have to do with some setting which handles the dataset.

Comment: Can you try to use another column for your `color`, and then try to the same with `fill` instead of `color`?

Comment: @mhh Yes I did that. fill produces the same behavior. Choosing another column also produces the same behavior.

Comment: UPDATE: more interesting things. I installed the package ggplotgui and ran it with the diamonds dataset. I generated a histogram in the GUI and then exited. In the console I ran
```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, color=cut)) +
geom_bar(position='identity')
```
and it worked. However, it reverted back when RStudio was restarted.